# Cannot type Password via SendKeys() in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to write a program using Selenium WebScraping to interact with my email. The code I pasted below is just for the login process. I changed the email and password.

```
from selenium import webdriver

#Edge
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

#Open the website
driver.get('https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&ct=1602431674&rver=7.0.6737.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https%3a%2f%2foutlook.live.com%2fowa%2f%3fnlp%3d1%26RpsCsrfState%3d2c3ee82f-9893-34e5-fd04-e3b4c3e2ccc4&id=292841&aadredir=1&CBCXT=out&lw=1&fl=dob%2cflname%2cwld&cobrandid=90015')

log_in_button = driver.find_element_by_name("loginfmt")

log_in_button.send_keys('myemail@outlook.com')

next_button = driver.find_element_by_id("idSIButton9")

next_button.click()

password_button = driver.find_element_by_name("passwd")

password_button.send_keys('my_password')
```

When I run this however (with the right email and password), the program cannot seem to enter the password at the last step. There is no error log, and my program enters my email just fine, but it cannot enter the password. I tried using several different ways to locate the HTML element including

```
find_element_by_type()

find_element_by_id()

find_element_by_class_name()
```

and also

```
find_element_by_css_selector()
```

Most of these methods ended up with StaleElementReferenceException, some ended up with Cannot Locate Element, and the rest didn't work at all.

Does anyone know a method to typing in a password via Selenium, I am assuming that either I am using the wrong element, or Microsoft purposely blocks this kind of behavior for some reason.

Any help is greatlly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: after next button click add a pause of some seconds suitably 5 seconds. or use `expected conditions` if you want it really fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to avoid `time.sleep()` wherever possible. `time.sleep()` unnecessary slow down your scrpits.

Best practice says always use **Explicit wait** to avoid synchronization issue.

Use `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`()

```
password_button =WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"passwd")))
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Further learning you can refer below [Explicit Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)